# What documents to show for "Evidence of family members remaining in your home country whilst you travel for Standard visiting visa"

Tags: uk, transit-visas, datv

I'm applying for a UK transit visa. One of my parents lives with me and is my direct dependent. They have no passport as of now and all of their documents point to an older address in a different city we used to live a few years back. What we currently use as her address proof is a gas connection registration document.

What documents can I submit for my caase for `Evidence of family members remaining in your home country whilst you travel for Standard visiting visa` in visa application?

Comment: Is there some reason you can't get updated documents for your parents?

Comment: @ChrisH lack of time. The travel is pretty soon and document updates take much time here.